# JavaScript/jQuery VIN Validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, coldfusion

Has anyone ever created a VIN Validator? I am trying to create a textbox where the user will enter in a Vehicle Identification Number and then JS/jQuery will validate if its correct or not in case they mistype the number.

I am very new to JS/jQuery and have found some examples but of course have not been able to get them to work correctly... Any one with any ideas or suggestions it would be greatly appreciated, especially if you can tell me how to set up what I have below to work properly!

Note: The [isVin() function](http://www.cflib.org/index.cfm?event=page.udfbyid&udfid=1710)  is courtesy of [cflib.org](http://www.cflib.org)

HTML:

```
<label name="vin">VIN</label>
<input type="text" name="vin" />
```

ColdFusion:

```
<cfscript>
/**
 * US Vehicle Identification Number (VIN) validation.
 * version 1.0 by Christopher Jordan
 * version 1.1 by RHPT, Peter Boughton &amp; Adam Cameron (original function rejected valid VINs)
 * 
 * @param v      VIN to validate (Required)
 * @return Returns a boolean. 
 * @author Christopher Jordan (cjordan@placs.net) 
 * @version 1, February 19, 2013 
 */
function isVIN(v) {
    var i = "";
    var d = "";
    var checkDigit = "";
    var sum = 0;
    var weights = [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 10, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2];
    var transliterations = {
        a = 1,    b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5, f = 6,    g = 7, h = 8,
        j = 1,    k = 2, l = 3, m = 4, n = 5,         p = 7,            r = 9,
                s = 2, t = 3, u = 4, v = 5, w = 6,    x = 7, y = 8,    z = 9
    };
    var vinRegex = "(?x)    ## allow comments
        ^                    ## from the start of the string
                            ## see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_Identification_Number for VIN spec
        [A-Z\d]{3}            ## World Manufacturer Identifier (WMI)
        [A-Z\d]{5}            ## Vehicle decription section (VDS)
        [\dX]                ## Check digit
        [A-Z\d]                ## Model year
        [A-Z\d]                ## Plant
        \d{6}                ## Sequence
        $                    ## to the end of the string
    ";

    if (! REFindNoCase(vinRegex, arguments.v)) {
        return false;
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= len(arguments.v); i++) {
        d = mid(arguments.v, i, 1);

        if (! isNumeric(d)) {
            sum += transliterations[d] * weights[i];
        } else {
            sum += d * weights[i];
        }
    }

    checkDigit = sum % 11;

    if (checkDigit == 10) {
        checkDigit = "x";
    }
    return checkDigit == mid(arguments.v, 9, 1);
}
</cfscript>
```

Test Code:

```
    <cfoutput>
<cfset vin = "1GNDM19ZXRB170064">
#vin#: #isVin(vin)#<br />
<cfset vin = "1FAFP40634F172825">
#vin#: #isVin(vin)#<br />
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: If your code is not working, describe exactly how it fails. Does it result in error messages? Wrong answers? No answers?

Comment: `writeOutput("#vin#: #isVin(vin)#<br />");` looks strange

Comment: `<cfscript>` means it was made for ColdFusion and won't work if you simply put it in you page.

Comment: I bet a Regular Expression would be a better way to do this.

Comment: @ZaneZ - Client and server side code (ie javascript vs cfml/cfscript) are two different things. Javascript does not know anything about CF code. If you want to invoke CF code onChange, you need to use ajax to submit an http request to the CF server. That said, why not use a javascript function? If you search I am sure it has been done before ..

Comment: The last section of the VIN can contain characters and not only digits. You validation routine will fail when it encounters low volume manufacturers or a manufacturer such as Ford who uses the 12 character as "A" (numeric equivalent of 1) for most passenger vehicles. I would suggest that you have another look at the regular expression routine for invalid characters. If the 3 character of the WMI is a 9, then it is a low volume manufacturer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a client-side solution using Regular Expressions.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#vin").on("keyup blur", function() {
    if (validateVin($("#vin").val()))
      $("#result").html("That's a VIN");
    else
      $("#result").html("Not a VIN");
  }).trigger("blur");
});
  
function validateVin(vin) {
  var re = new RegExp("^[A-HJ-NPR-Z\\d]{8}[\\dX][A-HJ-NPR-Z\\d]{2}\\d{6}$");
  return vin.match(re);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label name="vin">VIN</label>
<input type="text" id="vin" value="1FAFP40634F172825" />
<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: This answer only validate vin string format, but no validate "check digit", and it is the most important.

Comment: Just an FYI this doesn't correctly check VINs. There can be characters in the last 6 spots in the string.

Answer (score 18):

If you're decoding VINs for vehicles sold in North America<sup>1</sup>, you can validate the following:

1. That the VIN is 17 digits in length
2. If 17 digits, that the check digit (9th position) is correct

As you'll be checking the VIN in real time as the user types it in, it's important to be efficient. This means failing fast while the user is typing it in. While you can use regex for this task, it's far slower than simply checking the VIN's length. Once the VIN is 17 digits long then you can validate the check digit (which, incidentally, is itself *also faster* than regex - see below).

Regular expressions are not a good fit for VIN validation for a couple reasons:

1. Performance. It's not as fast as simply checking the length, and the trade-off for speed doesn't net you that much of an improvement in accuracy because you can't validate the check digit.
2. Accuracy. While it's true you can ensure a VIN meets the correct pattern in terms of length and valid characters, that is not enough. `KNDJB723025140702` is a valid VIN while `KNDJB723025140703` is not (the only difference is the last number). A regex solution will show both VINs as being valid, with the second being a false-positive and therefore incorrect.

Wikipedia has a [really good script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_identification_number#Example_Code) for performing check digit validation that also fails quickly by only validating the check digit if the VIN is 17 digits.

[In my own testing](https://jsperf.com/vin-decode), the script below is much, must faster (roughly 40x) than using regex to validate a VIN, and it has the added benefit of returning accurate results.

```js
$(function() {
  var $ctrl = $('#vin'),
    $msg = $('#validation-message');

  $ctrl.keyup(function() {
    if (validateVin($ctrl.val())) {
      $msg.html("VIN is valid!");
    } else {
      $msg.html("VIN is not valid");
    }
  });
});

function validateVin(vin) {
  return validate(vin);


  // source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_identification_number#Example_Code
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  function transliterate(c) {
    return '0123456789.ABCDEFGH..JKLMN.P.R..STUVWXYZ'.indexOf(c) % 10;
  }

  function get_check_digit(vin) {
    var map = '0123456789X';
    var weights = '8765432X098765432';
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 17; ++i)
      sum += transliterate(vin[i]) * map.indexOf(weights[i]);
    return map[sum % 11];
  }

  function validate(vin) {
      if (vin.length !== 17) return false;
      return get_check_digit(vin) === vin[8];
    }
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

VIN:
<input id="vin" type="text" />
<span id="validation-message"></span>
```

<sup>[1] Vehicles sold in the EU don't typically use a check digit, and for some cars can even be 18 digits in length (Mercedes).</sup>

Comment: Not working correctly it say WDF44781313229645 is not valid, and it is

Comment: I updated my answer to indicate it's for North American vehicles only (and those that use check digits). Most cars sold in the EU don't use a check digit. In that case, for simplicity, the regex solution is probably better, however some VINs can be 18 digits in length so some parsing of the WMI (first 3 digits) may be necessary.