# CSS for a jQuery Vin Validation

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have a jQuery function that Validates whether or not a VIN is valid.. What I am looking to do is try to figure out the CSS Where it will circle the text box and give a green check mark if its correct or if it is not correct a red border with a red X. This link towards the bottom has it how I want it to be but I cannot figure it out any help would be greatly appreciated. http://bootstrapvalidator.com/validators/vin/

```
$(function() {
  $("#vin").on("keyup blur", function() {
    if (validateVin($("#vin").val()))
      $("#result").html("That's a VIN");
    else
      $("#result").html("Not a VIN");
  });
});

function validateVin(vin) {
  var re = new RegExp("^[A-HJ-NPR-Z\\d]{8}[\\dX][A-HJ-NPR-Z\\d]{2}\\d{6}$");
  return vin.match(re);
}
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label name="vin">VIN</label>
<input type="text" id="vin" value="1FAFP40634F172825" />
<span id="result"></span>
```

Example Snippet Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26408196/4122820

Comment: where shall this checkmark / x come from? And when you say "circle the textbox" what do you mean?

Comment: lol I don't know I just wanted it similar to the example I provided. http://bootstrapvalidator.com/validators/vin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add or remove a css class..
try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#vin").on("keyup blur", function() {
    if (validateVin($("#vin").val())) {
      $("#result").html("That's a VIN");
      $("#vin").removeClass("not-ok").addClass("ok");
    } else {
      $("#result").html("Not a VIN");
      $("#vin").removeClass("ok").addClass("not-ok");
    }
  });
});

function validateVin(vin) {
  var re = new RegExp("^[A-HJ-NPR-Z\\d]{8}[\\dX][A-HJ-NPR-Z\\d]{2}\\d{6}$");
  return vin.match(re);
}
```

```css
.ok {
  border: 1px solid #090;
  background: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQRaDfem_skoZyavLgGvEiX37WkSH14deXWLHT1UQU4PiljxtUo) no-repeat center right;
}
.not-ok {
  border: 1px solid #900;
  background: url(https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRx3bIOGuKEPsFxbAtH8UmzSh0XHajuDoSSAAgPK2a4-hFmzXhWBQ) no-repeat center right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label name="vin">VIN</label>
<input type="text" id="vin" value="1FAFP40634F172825" />
<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: use an image as background of the input

Comment: what about the text part Its a Vin and Not a Vin How do you do the CSS on that?

Answer (score 0):

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/p9cm679w/2/)

```
.checked:after {
    content:'\2713';
    background:rgb(21, 181, 21);
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    line-height:25px;
    border-radius:50%;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
#result {
    display:inline-block;
}
.error {
    border:1px solid red;
}
input:focus{
    outline:0;
}
```