# enquiry.php limiting form field to a specific character limit

Tags: php, forms

I am looking too limit and enquiry form specifically too 17 characters for a motor vehicle VIN number, only 17 characters, is there a way of amending the following enquiry.php code to enforce this, as users keep bypassing the required field with fake VIN numbers:

```
<?php
    //if mysite.co.za is there in HTTP_REFERRER variable
    if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'mysite.co.za'))
    {
  //only process operation here
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = " ";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
$_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
$_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    header("Location: http://www.mysite.co.za/car-electronic-equipment-replacement-error.html"); 
  } else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
    function spamcheck($field) {
  //filter_var() sanitizes the e-mail
  //address using FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL
  $field=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

  //filter_var() validates the e-mail
  //address using FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL
  if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    return TRUE;
  } else {
    return FALSE;
  }
} 
//check if the email address is invalid
    $to = "info@mysite.co.za";
    $subject = "Key-Soft Enquiry Form";
    $name_field = $_POST['name'];
    $email_field = $_POST['email'];
    $number_field = $_POST['number'];
    $make_field = $_POST['make'];
    $model_field = $_POST['model'];
    $vin_field = $_POST['vin'];
    $location_field = $_POST['location'];
    $locked_field = $_POST['locked'];
    $lostKeys_field = $_POST['lostKeys'];
    $remoteKey_field = $_POST['remoteKey'];
    $info = $_POST['info'];
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers="From: $name_field <$email_field>" . "\r\n" .
   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $body = "From: $name_field\n 
    Email Address: $email_field\n  
    Phone Number: $number_field\n 
    Car Make: $make_field\n  
    Year Model: $model_field\n 
    Vin Number: $vin_field\r  
    Location of vehicle: $location_field\n 
    Is the car locked: $locked_field\n  
    Are all keys lost: $lostKeys_field\n
    Are they remote keys: $remoteKey_field\n  
    Additional Info: $info";

    header("Location: http://www.mysite.co.za/vehicle-security-key-duplication-thank-you.html");  
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

}
}
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you validate input on user interface at first?

Answer (score 0):

You could validate the input of the form before submitting (in javascript for an exemple)

And you definitly should control your data before processing it in php :

Depending of the official format VIN you could use a regex to verify if the submitted value is valid or not :

```
$vin_field = (string) $_POST['vin'];

if (!preg_match('/^(?:([A-HJ-NPR-Z]){3}|\d{3})(?1){2}\d{2}(?:(?1)|\d)(?:\d|X)(?:(?1)+\d+|\d+(?1)+)\d{6}$/', $vin_field)) {
    // the value is not correct, you should not save here
    // consider redirecting the user to the form page with an error
}
```

there is a [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314850/vin-validation-regex) about validating a VIN format with a regex.

For the javascript form fields validation, there are plenty of methods among the Internet.

There is also a [Stack overflow question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407015/javascript-jquery-vin-validator).

Answer (score 0):

You can check the lenght of a string using `int strlen ( string $string )` function, so in your case you could check your variable like this:

```
if ( strlen($vinfield) != 17){
   ///do something
}
```

But I would first of all validate your variable on input form. Like using html max lenght tag:

```
<input type="text" name="vin" maxlength="17" id="vin">
```

And then also use javascript to validate like so:

```
<script>
function validate() {
    submitFlag = true;
    if(document.yourForm.vin.value.length != 17){
        submitFlag=false;
        alert("ivalid length - 17 characters needed!");
    }
    return submitFlag;
}
</script>
```

And include this in your form tag:

```
onsubmit="return validate()"
```

Comment: The maxlength attribute won't prevent a user to type in nothing or a shorter string

Comment: Thats why wou should also use java script and php validation, max value just restricts the user a little.